# Designing ReactJS Enabled Contact Form

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get a contact form with ReactJS. Intended behavior:

1. Show the contact form on page load
2. On form submission, send data to server, remove the form and show a message

Problem:
After the form is submitted the message is not shown.
The form is not removed.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var ContactBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {name: '', message: '', email: '', formSubmitted: false};
  },
  handleContactSubmit: function() {
   // TODO: submit to the server
    this.setState({formSubmitted: true});
  },
  render: function() {
  if (this.state.formSubmitted) {
        return (
            <div className="alert alert-success">
            <p> The form was submitted. </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        This is the ContactBox
          <ContactForm onContactSubmit={this.handleContactSubmit}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var ContactForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {name: '', message: '', email: '', submitted: false};
  },
  handleNameChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({name: e.target.value});
  },
  handleEmailChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({email: e.target.value});
  },
  handleMessageChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({message: e.target.value});
 },
 handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = this.state.name.trim();
    var email = this.state.email.trim();
    var message = this.state.message.trim();
    if (!name || !email || !message) {
      return;
    }
    // TODO: send request to the server

    this.setState({name: '', email: '', message: '', submitted: true});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address" name="email" className="form-control" id="email" />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" name="name" className="form-control" id="name" />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
            <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" className="form-control" id="message" />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="btn btn-default" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ContactBox />,
  document.getElementById('contact-container')
);
```

Comment: You can find complete tutorial for this here : http://blog.malith.pro/how-to-create-a-contact-form-with-react-js-and-php/

Answer (score 2):

There are several things missing here.

1) `handleNameChange`, `handleEmailChange` and `handleMessageChange` are not hooked up to the change handlers of the appropriate fields so when it comes to `if (!name || !email || !message)`, it always evaluates as false.

2) You don't call `this.props.onContactSubmit` anywhere to tell the parent component that the form is submitted so it never redraws.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyb8tj1g/) for a working version.

Answer (score 1):

In `ContactBox`, `this.setState({submitted: true});` should be `this.setState({formSubmitted: true});`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. Even after correcting, the behavior is unchanged.